# Data Modelling with Mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

A simple question and wondering the best solution in MongoDB:

IN a SQL(RDBMS) environment we have two tables Customers and Products
So for this report we could simply write proper query:
REPORT: Give top ten customer have bought Sony products in last year
QUERY :

```
SELECT c.name,sum(price) total FROM customers c JOIN orderItems o ON(c.cid=o.cid) 
                               JOIN products p ON(p.pid=o.pid)
WHERE p.manufacture='SONY' AND o.date=2014
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY DESC total
```

What is the best approach for MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

I thing that the best approach for something like this is to save all necessary data straight to customer collection with structure similar to this:

```
{
    _id: <ObjectId1>,
    "customer_name": "XYZ",
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": 12345,
            "date": "2014",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "manufacturer": "SONY",
                    "product": "WALKMAN NWZ-W273L",
                    "color": "blue"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "manufacturer": "SONY",
                    "product": "VAIO XYZ",
                    "color": "silver"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So in this case we don't have products document independently, I mean we will have alot of duplicate products that redundant and it is instead of normalization and this is what exact I want to ask

Comment: You can also use [references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/#references) and [normalized data model](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models) in case of lot of duplicates. It depends on your application character, how you should use our customer collection and read performance of that collection.